# Have a sexed up weekend ahead! - is this correct

Tags: expressions, word-usage, compound-adjectives, idiom-meaning

> Have a sexed-up weekend ahead!

This is what my friend told me. He wanted to convey that I have a good/crazy/exciting weekend.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Sounds like something the Festrunk brothers might have said. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpFNC7puU2M, https://screen.yahoo.com/festrunk-brothers-000000414.html It was funny 35 years ago.

Comment: Strange that nobody has mentioned anything about the superfluous "ahead". Or is that just me? Doesn't the sentence sound much more natural without it?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't quite fit the context.

(to) [sex up](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/sex-up.html) (something)

> to make changes to something, especially a piece of writing, in order to make it seem more significant, exciting or interesting than it originally was

This expression is used with a presumption that the certain something was lacking and needed improvement, but was merely being 'dented and painted' instead.

I would understand a 'sexed-up weekend' as something of a desperate attempt to give a miserable weekend a quick makeover.

Answer (score -1):

If this person is banging or doing the banging throughout the whole weekend, then I would say that is one of the hottest ways to blow a weekend.

Is it correct? Expressions evolve and so this may be the start of something great. Something that could express to your friends how awesome it is for you to spend your time doing your favorite activity with little to no shame. In fact, sexed-up could really express how the weekend was really as good as exciting sex.

Comment: Incidentally, the expression has little to do with sex: "to enhance something to give it **greater appeal or impact**". http://www.theguardian.com/uk/2003/oct/09/books.politicsandthearts

Comment: @Kris As its most celebrated use in 2003 (Blair government to UK security services) demonstrates.